# How to access a Jersey bean from Spring FactoryBean?

Tags: spring, jersey, code-injection

I have a Spring BeanFactory and I need to inject httpHeaders to it.

```java
public class SpecificFactoryBean extends SomeFactoryBean<Exception> {

    @Context
    private HttpHeaders httpHeaders;

    protected SpecificFactoryBean() {
        super(Exception.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doRegistration(RegistryBuilder<Exception> registryBuilder) {
        registryBuilder.registerMapper(WebApplicationException.class, new ExceptionMapper<WebApplicationException>() {
            @Override
            public int map(WebApplicationException e) {

                httpHeaders.getSomeInfo();

                return 3;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now `@Context` doesn't work, so how can I do this?

Comment: `HttpHeaders` of which HTTP request?

Comment: Of current HTTP request

Comment: What is the Spring lifecycle of `SpecificFactoryBean`? Does it make any sense to talk about a 'current' HTTP request in the context of this class?